# Add a matrix to an array

Tags: r, arrays, matrix

I would like to add a matrix to an array.

```
databox<-matrix(1:30998*21,30998, 21)
resultemptybox <- array(rep(NA,30998*21*100), dim = c(30998, 21, 99))
resultemptybox[[1]] <- databox # I would like to add databox on the first dim of resultemptybox

resultbox1 <- array(c(databox,resultemptybox), dim = c(30998,21,100))
```

but str() shows,

```
str(resultbox1)
List of 65095800
```

and there's no data on the first dim of resultemptybox.

Thanks in advance,

###### update

Thanks to comments, I would like to add more details about the data and output I want to produce.

Here is my example data.

```
databox <- matrix(1:2*3,2,3)
resultemptybox <- array(rep(NA,2*3*3), dim = c(2,3,2))
```

The output I want to produce is

```
 > resultbox  
, , 1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]    6    6    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'add databox on the first dim of resultempty'? It might be much easier for you to manually present your desired result if you use a significantly smaller example, like: `databox<-matrix(1:3*21,3,3); resultemptybox <- array(rep(NA,3*3*100), dim = c(3, 3, 3))` . There's no reason we need 31,000 values to understand the logic of the replacement.

Comment: If I had to guess at what you wish, maybe `resultemptybox[,,1] <- databox` would do it?  Or `resultemptybox[1,,] <- databox` ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! I updated the example data and output I want to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on the fact that `matrix` and `array` objects are just vectors with dimensions, you can `c`oncatenate them together and add one more to the 3rd dimension:

```
da <- dim(resultemptybox)
array(c(databox, resultemptybox), dim=replace(da, 3, da[3]+1))
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    3    3
#[2,]    6    6    6
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA
#
#, , 3
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resultemptybox <- array(rep(NA,2*3*3), dim = c(2,3,3))
resultemptybox[,,1] <- databox

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]    6    6    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but 
> str(resultemplybox) 
 logi [1:30998, 1:21, 1:99] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
> resultbox1[1] <- list(databox)
> str(resultbox1)
List of 64444842
The structure of the array has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Using pipes and adding a vector to the original dims.

```
c(databox, resultemptybox) |> array(dim=dim(resultemptybox) + c(0, 0, 1))
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    3    3
# [2,]    6    6    6
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
```